# Hibernate executes select query after update

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

There was a problem with the Spring Boot 2.5.9 version of the project.

```
@Getter
@Builder
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class MyEntity {
    @Id
    UUID uuid;

    String username;

    String email;

    @ManyToOne
    ManyToOneField manyToOneField;
}
```

I am using the above entity, but when I try to update the above entity, an error occurs.

```
@Transactional
public void update() {
    MyEntity myEntity= messageSendLogRepository.findByUsername("only");
    myEntity.setUsername("update");
}
```

The following error occurs when executing this code.

```
Hibernate: 
    update 
        my_entity
    ...

Hibernate: 
    select 
        my_entity.uuid
    ...

2023-08-25 13:48:37.938 ERROR 89454 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] a.a.g.exception.CustomExceptionHandler.   : Object of class [app.my.project.domain.MyEntity] with identifier [01bab334-80d1-4813-891c-ab5d12402e96]: optimistic locking failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect)
```

In the select query, the updated record is being called again using pk.
The above error is the same with the save method by changing the persistent instance value without using transaction annotation.

Why does hibernate request a select query after the Update query in the above code?
The request from the select query is expected to cause a problem. Other entity classes that use @GeneratedValue for PK do not experience the same problem.

Is it a problem to use UUID as PK? Or is there another problem?
I'm curious about the cause of this error and how to solve it.

Comment: Please, check here https://github.com/bdshadow/stackoverflow/blob/master/spring/spring-data-id-generator-76974387/src/test/java/com/bocharov/service/MyTest.java. Try to comment/uncomment `@GeneratedValue` in the `MyEntity` - it works the same. Also, no exception is thrown